# Get max date from 3 tables and match them for success or failure in Informatica mapping

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to pick max date from 3 different tables and mark the job as success if its a match and fail if date from any table does not match. Could you suggest informatica transformations for the same without using the sql. Below is the sql based solution I came up with.

```
with 
A as (select TO_DATE(max(date1)) as date1,1 as seq from Table1),
B AS (select to_date(MAX(date2)) AS date2, 1 as seq from Table2),
C AS (SELECT to_date(max((date3)) AS date3,1 as seq FROM Table3) 
select CASE WHEN   
A.date1 = B.date2 and C.date3 = B.date2 and A.date1 = to_date(current_date) -1
THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as STATUS 
from 
A JOIN B ON A.SEQ=B.SEQ JOIN C ON A.SEQ=C.SEQ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use three sources with three Source Qualifiers. Use Aggregators to get the MAX. Join all the pipelines and check if any of the ports is null.

Let me know if you face any particular issue.

Comment: I got the 3 aggregators to get the max, but how do I join the pipelines from all the aggregators?

Comment: Three options: use joiners (2) - in case the dates will not match, simply nothing will get sent to target. Or add an Expression on each pipeline to add dummy port with 1 after each aggregator and use the dummy for joining. Final option is to add the dummy in the Source Qualifier and use this one for joining.